# Verdaccio private packages for each Registered User

Tags: authentication, npm, verdaccio

I want to host an npm package for each of my individual clients, and I want to publish those packages to a private Verdaccio instance. I also want ClientA to only have access to package A, and not to be able to access the packages for ClientB.
**How can I do that?**

My current plan is to simply edit the config file every time I get a new client, then restart the server. So, here's what that file might look like right now:

```yaml
packages:
  "@my-repo/client-a-*":
    access: admin client-a
    publish: admin
```

Then I get ClientB and I edit the file to look like this and restart the server:

```yaml
packages:
  "@my-repo/client-a-*":
    access: admin client-a
    publish: admin
  "@my-repo/client-b-*":
    access: admin client-b
    publish: admin
```

I think this would allow ClientA to have readOnly access to client-a packages, and then ClientB would have readOnly access to client-b packages. Do you think this will work? *Edit: I confirmed the above does work, allbeit a kind of tedious and manual solution.*

Ok - now, can I simplify this with regex?? Can I use group names or regex to match the client name with their package directory? It might look like this (*the config below is a guess*):

```yaml
packages:
  "@my-repo/$userId-*":
    access: admin $userId
    publish: admin
```

So, in this rule `$userId` acts as a variable, and it would result in every registered user only having access to packages published with the prefix of their own username. Is that possible, and how can I do?

**Edit: No. It's not possible. See answer below.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping multiple users into a "group" is NOT supported, per [this thread and comment](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/discussions/2173#discussioncomment-586438) (Sept, 2018) by the core maintainer himself:

> It's not possible in that way, currently, user === group. So, you must define all users are allowed in each section (access, publish).

However, it appears at least a small handful of developers have searched for this type of a solution:

- https://github.com/btshj-snail/snail-verdaccio-group
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/verdaccio-groups

So, I'll just have to tediously edit the config file to add/remove users and packages for them each specifically. Fortunately, Docker makes it pretty easy to just restart the service.